# What is ios::in|ios::out?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I was reading some project code and I found this,here `MembersOfLibrary()` is a constructor of `class MenberOfLibrary`

```cpp
class MembersOfLibrary {
  public:
    MembersOfLibrary();
    ~MembersOfLibrary() {}
    void addMember();
    void removeMember();
    unsigned int searchMember(unsigned int MembershipNo);
    void searchMember(unsigned char * name);
    void displayMember();

  private:
    Members    libMembers;

};

MembersOfLibrary::MembersOfLibrary() {

    fstream memberData;
    memberData.open("member.txt", ios::in|ios::out);
    if(!memberData) {
    cout<<"\nNot able to create a file. MAJOR OS ERROR!! \n";
    }
    memberData.close();
}
```

What is `ios::in|ios::out`?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- `ios::in` allows input (read operations) from a stream.
- `ios::out` allows output (write operations) to a stream.
- `|` (bitwise OR operator) is used to combine the two `ios` flags,
  meaning that passing `ios::in | ios::out` to the constructor
  of `std::fstream` enables *both* input and output for the stream.

---

**Important things to note:**

- `std::ifstream` automatically has the `ios::in` flag set.
- `std::ofstream` automatically has the `ios::out` flag set.
- `std::fstream` has neither `ios::in` or `ios::out` automatically
  set. That's why they're explicitly set in your example code.

Comment: Why do we need bitwise OR, just a logical OR operator cant be used here ?

Comment: Logical and bitwise OR are two completely different things. A logical OR deals only with `bool` values. For example, it evaluates the second expression only if the first expression evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Whereas a bitwise OR (which deals with integer values) goes through both values bit by bit and sets the bit in the resulting value if the bit was set in either of the two input values, thus resulting in a combining effect.

Comment: good concise answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
 memberData.open("member.txt", ios::in|ios::out);
```

ios::in is used when you want to read from a file

ios::out is used when you want to write to a file

ios::in|ios::out means ios::in or ios::out, that is whichever is required is used

Here's a useful link

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 5):

`ios::in` and `ios::out` are [openmode flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), and in your case combined with a binary *or* (`|`) operation. Thus the file is opened for reading and writing.

Comment: On that cppreference.com reference page, where in the world does it tell us that `ios::` is the namespace `in` and `out` are in?